# Swap values in a list nested from a pandas series - HAVE SOLUTION AT THE END of the post

Tags: pandas, list, for-loop, series, compare-and-swap

I'm trying to analyse the **play by play of a basketball game**, my purpose now it's to **change the line up**, depending in the **substitutions** in each play.

[example of the table with values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bYy0T.png)

In the image you can see the columns I'm using to swap the values of the list while line ups are recorded.

**pbp** is the dataframe and **columns** [["players", "actionType", "subType", "starters"]], the dataframe is ordered by **gameID** and by **action number**.

| gameID | actionNumber | team | players | actionType | subType | starters |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1858411 | 643 | MALVIN | N. Pomoli | foulon |  | [L. Capalbo, J. Cabillon, F. Haller, N. Pomoli... |
| 1858411 | 644 | TROUVILLE | F. Soto | substitution | out | [S. Massa, D. Tintorelli, J. Ducasse, M. Mayor... |
| 1858411 | 645 | TROUVILLE | N. Marotta | substitution | in | [S. Massa, D. Tintorelli, J. Ducasse, M. Mayor... |
| 1858411 | 646 | MALVIN | N. Pomoli | freethrow | 1of2 | [L. Capalbo, J. Cabillon, F. Haller, N. Pomoli... |

The dataframe works like this: the **action type** column will indicate when there's a **substitution** and **sub type** will tell if **goes in or out of the court**, player will indicate the player that is involved in that action. Starters is the initial line up of the game.

My **initial idea** was using a **loop** for with idx, row, **itering all rows**, identifying when it's a substitution made and if the players goes in or out, so I could **append** him to the list, or **remove** him from the **list**.

[Code used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iDYGB.png)

```
lineup = []
for idx, row in pbp.iterrows():
if row["actionType"] == "jumpball" and row["player"] is not None:
    lineup.append(row["starters"].copy())
    print(str(row["team"]) + " " + str(row["starters"]))
if row["actionType"] == "substitution" and row["subType"] == "in" and row["player"] not in row["starters"]:
    print(f"Team {row.team} player {row.player} goes in")
    a = row["starters"]
    a.append(row.player)
    lineup.append(a.copy())
    print(row.starters)
if row["actionType"] == "substitution" and row["subType"] == "out" and row["player"] in row["starters"]:
    print(f"Team {row.team} player {row.player} goes bench")
    b = row["starters"]
    b.remove(row.player)
    lineup.append(b.copy())
    print(row["starters"])
else:
    lineup.append(row["starters"].copy())
```

The problem is once it's finish, the **last line up** is the one that it's **preserved** for that team and that gameID.

[Final result with same line up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VLBDo.png)

¿Any ideas how to solve it?

¡Thank you!

---

```
team = []
lineup = []

for idx, row in pbp.iterrows(): # iterate all the rows of our dataframe
    equipo = row["team"] # Declare what's the time that it's in that row
    rival = pbp[(pbp["gameID"] == row["gameID"]) & (pbp["team"] != equipo)]
    
    if row["actionType"] == "jumpball": # If the action is a jumpball (where the game starts, check who wins and lost that jump)
                                        # and the lineup the team is using in that moment which is the starters
        if row["subType"] == "won":
            lineup.append(row.starters.copy()) # append the starters players
            team.append(equipo) # append the team
            print(f"{idx}: {row.team} El jugador {row.player} gana el salto: " + str(lineup[idx]))
        
        elif row["subType"] == "lost":
            lineup.append(row.starters.copy()) # append the starter players
            team.append(equipo) # append the team
            print(f"{idx}: {row.team} El jugador {row.player} pierde el salto: " + str(lineup[idx]))
        
        else: # There are jumpballs with other subtypes, and we won't record them
            lineup.append(np.nan)
            team.append(np.nan)
            print(f"{idx}: Se produce una lucha: " + str(lineup[idx-1]))
            
    elif row["actionType"] == "substitution": # if the action is a substitution we need to check if it's in or out
       
        if row["subType"] == "in": # Check an in-substitution
        
            numero_ultimo_quinteto = max([i for i in range(len(team)) if team[i] == equipo]) # Number of last lineup of the team
            current_lineup = lineup[numero_ultimo_quinteto].copy() # Obtain the last lineup
            current_lineup.append(row.scoreboardName) # Append the player that's going inside
            lineup.append(current_lineup.copy()) # Add the copy to our list
            team.append(equipo)
        
            print(f"{idx}: El jugador {row.player} del equipo {row.team} entra en pista: " + str(lineup[idx]))
        
        
        else: 
        
            numero_ultimo_quinteto = max([i for i in range(len(team)) if team[i] == equipo]) # Number of last lineup of the team
            current_lineup = lineup[numero_ultimo_quinteto].copy() # Obtain the last lineup
            current_lineup.remove(row.scoreboardName) # Remove the player that goes to bench
            lineup.append(current_lineup.copy()) # Add the copy to our list
            team.append(equipo)
            print(f"{idx}:El jugador {row.player} del equipo {row.team} sale de pista: " + str(lineup[idx]))
        
        
    else: # There are other actions that doesn't require a substitution, so we need to keep the previous lineup of the team
        
        if pbp["team"].iloc[idx] == equipo: # if a team performs the action 
            
            numero_ultimo_quinteto = max([i for i in range(len(team)) if team[i] == equipo]) # Number of last lineup of the team
            
            current_lineup = lineup[numero_ultimo_quinteto].copy() # Last lineup
            
            lineup.append(current_lineup.copy()) # Add the copy of the last lineup to the list
            team.append(equipo)
            
            print(f"{idx}: No hay sustitución: " + str(team[idx]) + " " + str(lineup[idx]))
            
            
        else: # if a team is not recorded means that action is a period, timeout, actions outside of the play
            
            lineup.append(np.nan)
            team.append(np.nan)
            print(f"{idx}: No hay acción equipo {lineup[idx]}")
```

The **previous code** was not well organized with the if statements, and the use of copy() functions weren't made very good.

Finally the code that gave me the **result** is with lists, **checking** the **starters** of the game and recording them, after **having** the starter **lineup** of the teams, what I needed was to **update** the lineups *wheter they made a substitution or another action*, if there was **no subsitution**, **keep** the previous team **lineup**, if there was a **subtitution**, **update** that **lineup**.

Comment: don't add pictures, share the sourcecode + sample of the df so it can be easy to reproduce it

Comment: it is still hard to follow your question. are you trying to monitor the team squad during a game? you said the games are sorted by gameID but the example is not sorted, in the substitution, how did you plan to check with whom player he was switched?

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake creating the table. I'll edit it

Comment: Using the play by play statistics, in the column "actionType" I can identify when the team makes a substitution, and with "subType" I can identify if the players goes in or out. Going step by step in the code: I check when is the jumpball, that five players that are the starters, are the starter lineups. Then has in each row we can identify substitutions in and out, we append or remove them from that list of 5 players. The resulting list lineup is the list that will be added to the dataframe as a column.

Comment: what is the expected output?

Comment: TROUVILLE ['S. Massa', 'D. Tintorelli', 'J. Ducasse', 'M. Mayora', 'M. Marotta']
Team TROUVILLE player S. Massa goes bench
['D. Tintorelli', 'J. Ducasse', 'M. Mayora', 'M. Marotta']
Team TROUVILLE player J. Ducasse goes bench
['D. Tintorelli', 'M. Mayora', 'M. Marotta']
Team TROUVILLE player D. Tintorelli goes bench
['M. Mayora', 'M. Marotta']
Team TROUVILLE player S. Tucuna goes in
['M. Mayora', 'M. Marotta', 'S. Tucuna']
Team TROUVILLE player P. Gomez goes in
['M. Mayora', 'M. Marotta', 'S. Tucuna', 'P. Gomez']

Comment: That's the output I got from the code I posted, when I print it, that's what would be in the lineup list. When I look into the list, it only takes the last value of the lineup in the gameID and actionNumber

Comment: Tomer S, thank you for your help. I've finally got the solution, I'll share it in the post, therefore some other people that can have the question can look for it in here.